Wide unbreakable equation in two column text?
I have a long unbreakable equation. The text is in two columns, I am looking for a way to add the equation (numbered!) at the location where it is quoted, in a way that breaks the text. Currently the equation just overlaps the text in the next column, I have seen examples where a line is added to the other column to indicate it breaks, but cannot reproduce it.
e.g.,
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
abcdefg = \\
&\frac{abcdefghijkl + urgntcrskugn }{shgcsurlkcnglesrukfgnlckusnrcs +jsakdcgnlurskgcnilruydfnctcdfgdjygggb + asdvfhjk}.
  \end{align}
\end{document}


\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}  are you really using that input encoding this century? almost every editor (including editors on windows) default to UTF-8 these days. Certainly the file as posted to this site can not be using that encoding as pasting it here will convert it to utf-8 making that declaration wrong

Your example produces ! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures; as you can not nest align in equation delete the equation enviornment you just want align (or better here would be multline

Welcome to TeX.SE!

This is(was?) done in Physical Review D, for example. Maybe you can find some template and see how they did it and try to copy the ideas. (In my opinion, breaking like that also breaks the flow when reading, so maybe it is better to flush it to the top/bottom at least.)

Here's one example based on stfloats environment. By default in two column documents, LaTeX adds a special environment <float>*, e.g. figure* which span contents across a page, which I believe is what you want. However, these floats are placed at the top of the next "available" page.
stfloats, on the other hand, adds extra options [t] and [b] which puts such floats at the top or at the bottom, respectively. For instance, the example below contains a reference and a long equation on the same page. In your article, however, you will likely need to play with texts to achieve a desired effect. It's just it might be easier with stfloats.
The code:
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stfloats}               % Add bottom option for starred float, s.a. "float*"
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}   % Colourful links
\usepackage{blindtext}              % Dummy text

\title{The Title}
\author{First last}
\date{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{figure*}[b]
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:abcdefg}
        X = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 + f^2 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 + f^2 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 + f^2}
    \end{equation}
\end{figure*}

\section{First}
\blindtext[2]

Reference to equation \ref{eq:abcdefg}.

\section{Second}
\blindtext[2]

\blindtext[2]

\blindtext[3]

\end{document}



I suggest you load the mathtools package (a superset of the amsmath package) and use that package's \splitfrac macro to split the denominator across three rows.
The line at the top of the following screenshot is produced by \hrule; it's there merely as a way of indicating the width of the column.

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\splitfrac' macro

\begin{document}
\hrule       % just to illustrate width of column

\begingroup  % limit scope of next instruction
\small       % may not be necessary
\begin{multline}
abcdefg = \\
\frac{abcdefghijkl+ urgntcrskugn}{\splitfrac{shgcsurlkcnglesrukfgnlckusnrcs}%
{\splitfrac{{}+jsakdcgnlurskgcnilruydfnctcdfgdjygggb}%
           {+asdvfhjk}}}.
\end{multline}
\endgroup

\end{document}

